# How to multiply a BigDecimal by an integer in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How do you multiply a BigDecimal by an integer in Java? I tried this but its not correct.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class Payment {
    int itemCost;
    int totalCost = 0;

    public BigDecimal calculateCost(int itemQuantity,BigDecimal itemPrice){
        itemCost = itemPrice.multiply(itemQuantity);
        totalCost = totalCost + itemCost;
    return totalCost;
   }
```

Comment: What problem are you getting?

Comment: I'd assume it's the compilation error since `multiply` takes another `BigDecimal`?

Comment: How do you know that it's not correct?

Comment: You should probably be using `BigDecimal` for `itemCost` and `totalCost`. After all, what if `itemPrice * itemQuantity` is more than will fit in an `int`? (And if that can never happen, why are you using `BigDecimal` to start with?)

Comment: Define "it's not correct". Not an adequate problem statement. We can't tell whether you mean "compile error", "incorrect result", "computer exploded", ...

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have a lot of *type-mismatches* in your code such as trying to put an `int` value where `BigDecimal` is required. The corrected version of your code:

```
public class Payment
{
    BigDecimal itemCost  = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal totalCost = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public BigDecimal calculateCost(int itemQuantity, BigDecimal itemPrice)
    {
        itemCost  = itemPrice.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(itemQuantity));
        totalCost = totalCost.add(itemCost);
        return totalCost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh.  I was right about the `BigDecimal(int)` constructor. :P

Comment: Using `BigDecimal.valueOf(itemQuantity)`, instead of the constructor, will reuse BigDecimals zero through ten, avoiding probable new object construction.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I would set the scale of the BigDecimal so that I dont end up on lengthy numbers. 
The integer 2 in the BigDecimal initialization below sets the scale.

Since you have lots of mismatch of data type, I have changed it accordingly to adjust.

```
class Payment   
{
      BigDecimal itemCost=new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO,  2);
      BigDecimal totalCost=new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO,  2);

     public BigDecimal calculateCost(int itemQuantity,BigDecimal itemPrice)
       { 
           BigDecimal   itemCost = itemPrice.multiply(new BigDecimal(itemQuantity)); 
             return totalCost.add(itemCost); 
       }
  }
```

BigDecimals are Object , not primitives, so make sure you initialize `itemCost` and `totalCost` , otherwise it can give you nullpointer while you try to add on `totalCost` or `itemCost`

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the issue about the scale. While you're at it, please note that your multiplication will end up with `itemCost` having a scale of `4`, not `2`: "Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this × multiplicand), and whose scale is (this.scale() + multiplicand.scale())" https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply-java.math.BigDecimal-

Answer (score 2):

First off, `BigDecimal.multiply()` returns a `BigDecimal` and you're trying to store that in an `int`.

Second, it *takes* another `BigDecimal` as the argument, not an `int`.

If you just use the `BigDecimal` for all variables involved in these calculations, it should work fine.